# grab two strings by pattern from html

Tags: shell, sed, grep, html

```html
        <DL><p>
            <DT><A HREF="https://www.gnu.org/gnu/" ADD_DATE="1650679138" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQC
AIAAACQkWg2AAACoklEQVQ4jT2PP0hCURTGz729rKwEkR6CkdFreVQSWWGZVItYEA5CZEPQWCC0N4ZCRGNDQw05tCQtIq8peDSUEPZnyyGUCkSLHPIp9917Gh54ho8D349zvo9
wzimlX19f+Xy+2WyOjY0pimKz2SiliNhqtfL5/O/vbygUcrlcQgiCiJqmHRwcAIDX61VVdXV11e/3AwAA3Nzc5HK5t7e3RqOxv78fDofJz8/P7u7u9/f31dWVw+GoVqvFYhEAZ
Fn++PhwuVwTExMAsLOzUy6X0+k0lMvllZWVy8tLRCyVSrFYzLq9tbUVCAS6u7tPTk4Q8fHxcW5u7vX1VTJN0zCMv7+/Wq2WSCTu7+/j8biiKKqqRqPRdDqdSqUmJycZY61WizF
G7Xb74OBgMplcWlqKRCLPz89+v39zc1OWZavr9fX1+vr6xsbG6Oio2+0GzrmmaYFAYHZ2FhE555VKJRgMFgqFUqmkKAoi7u3tLSws6LrOOSdCCEKIruv1en1tbU3TtPHx8b6+P
gDo7++/uLjo7e2dnp4uFAqxWEwIIQkhKKWdnZ0OhyOTyfT09MiyLEnS4eHhwMBAJBJ5eXkpFoszMzNCCACQKKVCiGazmcvlgsHg8PCwzWZ7f3+PRqPVatXj8RiGwTkfGhrinHd
0dFBCCCIuLy+HQiGfz/fw8MAY6+rqqtfr8/Pzn5+f2WzW4/FYyRFRQkTridfrFUKMjIzc3t6Gw+FarXZ6esoYczqddrvdwgghlBBCCAEAVVUrlcri4mImkzk+Pvb5fE6n0zCMe
DxOKbVoAABEREQhBCI2Gg3TNHVdB4BsNnt2dvb09ISIjLE2A+3NUs45Y+z8/FySJAA4OjoSQpimabmIKAGA1aathJDt7W232313dzc1NdXObM0/+0mFhpRFricAAAAASUVORK5
CYII=">gnu/linux</A>
            <DT><A HREF="https://crontab.guru/" ADD_DATE="1651093395" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAIA
AACQkWg2AAAB8UlEQVQ4jW2SXUjTURjGn+f4b0XKYrpBYG4j3HY1IpBRDgIJg4IRol304UVgF5kRQRBBEATVuvPOCPGmL+qiO7NMyCi7WMJKsLAbx/BmpEwNUUb8ny7+HzrocD
gczvk973nf5z2Mx9tIkHRWACQAkJQEQAIASRIkWT5tDHcK4MrhcAABAbRIGkNf5nOOxpPCtl2N5dDG0EHJ4MCdo70nWqOhAADALhfm7z6uXrzSNjk08bwCy6eNQeelrvvXUxFg
tVyZnl3bwJ50x4FoJj2aAbA6uUwSFunSuXt9+Z7wVnnx1tX3bxa3s788dmEw01gtLrwEABgSJCK5rnxP+PdM4UhuaqJEb4DkyLMlAF9f/HTIhnA4ZEx4+OmxaK18vndmjaA3na
KbmwINldLtJxXnTYtEpD+Tbaq9uva2tI0Bcp1amfv18LvvGwyA08f3o1p+9AE7DK0bXtcgwQAI7jWobq14TYUA91oSWlp2ux2XJBkAgV3Awdi5+kiSlE6MjA9Mfzx5yDsEYEmY
/bHen2q+WehrzX8ee10NpkOHO2Ldp9o7U43A5viDT9+88BKYSsVJDo2eHczuq0v872bh3dzwjWJRkmDbsm1JYjIZdyxvzybPdEdQq/1Z3liYX5r6su6X4aC2LQlMJGL/+3bwCn
Vpb4N/csD9UHGZQoAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">Crontab</A>
```

I want to extract the description and the href, for example   `gnu/linux https://www.gnu.org/gnu/` to pass then to dmenu

I can get them individually like so `grep -o -P '(?<=">).*(?=</A>)' bookmark.html`
and `grep -o -P '(?<=HREF=).*(?= ADD)'  bookmark.html` but I don't know how to combine them or even with sed or awk.

Comment: Don't try to parse html with regex. Can you provide the real URL ?

Comment: yeh I know that, Probably I should use something like `pup` to parse html, but i would prefer to stick with the default tools of the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the HTML to XML and then use an XML-aware parser to pick out the relevant items.

```
xmlstarlet format -H index.html 2>/dev/null |
    xmlstarlet select -T -t -m '//a' -v 'concat(., " ", @href)' -n 2>/dev/null
```

While I was testing I wrapped the sample extract in `<root>`...`</root>`, but you shouldn't need to do that with HTML. The resulting output, with each pair of fields on a line, space separated:

```
gnu/linux https://www.gnu.org/gnu/
Crontab https://crontab.guru/
```

You might find it better to provide the URL (which has no spaces) and then the description. Or use a tab to separate the fields.

If you don't already have `xmlstarlet` it's in a standard package so very easy to install.